# Splitting file based on size, but make sure that it ends with newline

Tags: text-processing, files, newlines, split

I am able to use the `split` command successfully to split large file into multiple smaller files. This is being achieved by following command

```
split -b 1G $temp_path $final_filepath
```

But only caveat is that these files many times contain last line which is split across 2 files. Is there any way to avoid that using `split` or any other command ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, don't use the `-b` parameter. From the [split(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/split):

> -b, --bytes=SIZE
> put SIZE bytes per output file
>
> -C, --line-bytes=SIZE
> put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
>
> -l, --lines=NUMBER
> put NUMBER lines per output file

By using `-b` you are telling split to deliniate files at a specific size in bytes (or Kb or MB). If that is the middle of a line, too bad.

Split supports 'number of lines' and a 'max output file size comprised of whole lines'.

Instead, try this:

```
split -C 1G $temp_path $final_filepath
```

The `-C` flag is not available on all versions of split (notably OS X / Darwin). In that case you can use `gsplit` which is available in the GNU `coreutils` package on [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) and [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/coreutils/summary).

Comment: did not read the man page `carefully` enough.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us. I'm just glad I was working with split earlier today and happened to know the answer off the cuff. :)